# XPath to select multiple elements?

Tags: xml, xpath, element

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<a>
   <b>
      <c>110</c>
      <d>periodendyear="2019"</d>
      <e>
         <f>
            <code>xyz</code>
            <value>54</value>
         </f>
      </e>
      <e>
         <f>
            <code>xy</code>
            <value>6</value>
         </f>
      </e>
   </b>
</a>
```

How would you select all the `a`, `d` and `code` and `value` elements that are children of `b` elements?

Basically, something like:

```
//b | //f
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How would you select all the `a`, `d` and `code` and `value` elements that are children of `b` elements?

Note that there are no `code` and `value` children of `b` elements, so I'll assume that you meant *descendants*, not just children.

This XPath,

```
//b//*[self::a or self::d or self::code or self::value]
```

will select all `a`, `d` and `code` and `value` elements that are descendants of all `b` elements anywhere in the document.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to select all the `c`, `d`, `code`, `value` nodes that are *descendants* of the `b` node with the single XPath expression try

```
//b//*[name()=('c', 'd', 'code', 'value')]
```

Comment: Note that `=('c', 'd', 'code', 'value')`  requires XPath 2.0.